# Using which wrapper Google Chrome was embed in Talk.to windows client

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, word-wrap, tidesdk

[talk.to](http://talk.to) windows client uses embedded Google Chrome for its GUI. Basically, it wraps Google Chrome packaged with its chat extension.

I m just curious using which wrapper it was built? Any of the below?

- [CEF](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)
- [Awesomium](https://www.awesomium.com/)
- [Asterclick WBEA](http://asterclick.drclue.net/WBEA.html) (very easy to use, but limited features*)
- [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/)

Answer (score 1):

talk.to client seems to be using chrome as we can see linux and osx clients are chrome apps.

If you are interested in developing desktop application.. you should checkout TideSDK (http://tidesdk.org/). TideSDK is promising because it is only SDK which provides support for Windows, Linux, OSx and also all latest versions of them including windows 8, Mountain Lion and ubuntu 12.04, 12.10.

Answer (score 1):

it was built in with CEF. It is said in the about page of chrome